# Processing data under load with GenServer (gen_server)

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am testing the following pattern in a GenServer:

```
  def handle_info({:tcp, _, data}, s) do
    # IO.puts "\nrx: \n#{Base.encode16(data)}\n"

    extra = _proc_data(<<s.extra::binary, data::binary>>)

    :inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)

    {:noreply, %{s | extra: extra}}
  end
```

There is a problem when data comes in fast, and i'm unable to update state before  `:inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)` releases new data

Must  `{:noreply, %{s | extra: extra}}` be the last line for `handle_info`, or can I perform the `:inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)` last?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `:noreply` does need to be the last thing since it is the return value of the function. Regarding updating the state, would it solve your problem to  have another `GenServer` call from this function? I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the exact problem but you might start down that path as a refactor.

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo The problem is from previous call to `_proc_data` I may have extra bytes which i need to hold in `GenServer state`, and pre-pend to any new data before processing. The requirement to call `{:noreply, new_state}` last in `handle_info` becomes an issue, since calling `:inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)` will release new data before i have saved the extra from previous step

Comment: As long as `_proc_data` doesn't `receive` any messages, your code is correct as written. Any additional data released by the `setopts` call will simply be placed in the message queue, and `gen_server` will call your `handle_info` function again. The effect is the same as if the data had arrived just after `handle_info` returned.

Comment: Thanks. I have just figured that out now. @sasajuric pointed out that `handle_*` are not re-entrant. That helped me tack down the cause to something else.

Comment: @legoscia what if `_proc_data` does a `gen_tcp:send`? I guess any received data still queues up sequentially correct?

Comment: Yes, sending data wouldn't have any effect on the message queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique I've used in the past is to send the data to another `GenServer` for processing. This would allow the current process to call `:inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)` faster.

```
def handle_info({:tcp, _, data}, s) do
    # IO.puts "\nrx: \n#{Base.encode16(data)}\n"

    GenServer.cast(s.processor, {:data, data})

    :inet.setopts(s.socket, active: :once)

    {:noreply, s}
end
```

Processor:

```
defmodule DataProcessor do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], opts)

  def init(_), do: {:ok, %{}}

  def handle_cast({:data, data}, state) do
    extra = _proc_data(s.extra <> data)    
    {:noreply, %{state| extra: extra}}
  end

  defp _proc_data(data) do
    ...
  end
end
```